При компиляция приложения, написанного с помощью фреймворка типа QT, включается вся библиотека?
Есть приложение, написанное с помощью фреймворка. Соответственно внутри него импортируются всякие классы готовые из библиотеки.
Когда компилируется такое приложение, то в объем кода попадает вся библиотека, которую мы импортировали или только та часть, необходимая для выполнения нашего кода приложения?

spring - это же вообще java, правильно? потому убрал упомнинание из вопроса. если нужен ответ про java - задайте, пожалуйста, отдельный вопрос.

@aleksandrbarakin по-моему, что Spring, что QT были приведены просто для примера, а вопрос скорее всего общий для любых фреймворков.

@Byb, полностью с вами согласен, и ответ на вопрос в таком случае должен быть слишком обширным для данного сайта. я просто пытаюсь «спасти» вопрос.

При нормальным вызове линкера в загрузочный модуль попадет только необходимая часть (и ничего для обширного ответа тут можно и не писать)

@avp Увы,, это верно для boost, например, но не для таких монстров как Qt. Там, при включении любого графического элемента управления, подключается модуль widgets целиком: каждый виджет имеет зависимость  от фичи Accessibility, которая имеет зависимость, от всех виджетов. Т.е. приложение с двумя кнопками, будет включать код отрисовки docking windows и т.д. Чтобы этого избежать, приходится шаманить еще на уровне самостоятельной сборки Qt из исходников.

@Chorkov, значит Дейкстра был прав, утверждая, что "C++ damages the brain"
